# Create a Camel route that sends one value to REST and a different value to another camel component?

Tags: apache-camel

10:39

I want to create a route that returns a JSON response to a user via REST and then sends data to BigQuery. Something like:

```
rest()
.get("/getSchedule")
.route()
.process("business logic - creates object with schedule AND big query statement")
```

The problem is that these are 2 different things. For the REST response to be correct I have to put the object with the schedule into the exchange body. But in order to send the BigQuery statement to the BigQuery component I have to set the BQ statement into the exchange object. Which messes up the REST response.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I figured this out. What I want is a solution that returns with the REST response immediately and sends some other data to BigQuery as well. Since the 2nd step may block I will put an asynchronous process in between (could be a queue but in my case was Google PubSub). My route looks like this (leaving out things like .consumes, .outTypes for clarity):

```
rest()
  .get("/getSchedule")
  .route()
  .processor(<business_logic>)
  .wiretap("direct:pubsub");

from("direct:pubsub")
   .process("processorA")
   .to("google-pubsub topic");

from("google-pubsub subscription")
   .processor("processorB")
   .to("google-bigquery");
```

The first processor with business logic computes desired schedule data, puts it into a POJO, and puts a bigquery statement into an exchange header named "event".

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange) 
{
   <business logic>
   ScheduleData sData = new ScheduleData();
   <insert values>
   exchange.getIn().setBody(sData)

   String insertStatement = "<insert_stmt>"
   exchange.getIn().setHeader("event",insertStatement )
}
```

The ScheduleData data becomes the response I want. Now ProcessorA does some needed work before we put the data into the topic:

```
@Override
public void process(Exchange exchange)
{
  String stmt = (String)exchange.getIn().getHeader("event")
  byte[] data = <convert "stmt" into UTF8 bytes>
  exchange.getIn().setBody(data);
}
```

Now the BigQuery data is sent through PubSub, received by Camel, and sent to ProcessorB.

```
public void process(Exchange exchange)
{
  byte[] data = exchange.getIn().getBody(byte[].class)
  String stmt = <convert UTF8 bytes to string>
  exchange.getIn().setBody(stmt);
```

Putting the statement back in the exchange body it can now be sent to the BiqQuery component. Which I have not solved yet. But at least the wiretap method was the answer to my use case.